# Using Ruby Stomp Gem to work with persistent messages and redelivery on exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemq-classic, stomp, activemessaging

I'm trying to use the Stompgem (https://github.com/stompgem/stomp) and Activemessaging (https://github.com/kookster/activemessaging) in a rails app to publish persistent/reliable messages (to be resilient even if subscriber crashes part-way through processing)

Is there a way to persistently publish to a topic have re-deliveries work to any failed/timed/error'd subscribers?

**Using stompgem for publishing:**

```
@client.publish("/topic/" + topic_name, data_hash.to_json, {:persistent => true})
```

Reference: https://github.com/stompgem/stomp/blob/dev/examples/publisher.rb

**Using activemessaging for topic subscription**

```
class ProcessPublisherProcessor < ApplicationProcessor

    subscribes_to :process_publisher, :ack => :client

    def on_message(message)
        logger.debug "ProcessPublisherProcessor received: " + message
    end

end
```

I have tried the recommendations to add the :persistent => true into the client publish method and also adding :ack => :client into the subscriber.

Terminating the subscriber partway through the on_message (either by stopping the ruby process or throwing a random exception) results in the message not being redelivered by the broker (Activemq in this case).

Goal:

- Publish reliably to a topic
- Subscribe receives message from a topic and explicitly acknowledges that the message has been consumed
- Up to X redelivery attempts by the broker before putting the message in  DLQ (dead letter queue) of my choosing.

Thank you,